# setting up Domain and Sub Domain in IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

May be this one is stupid question:

I have to deploy 2 applications, Client and Service (WCF 4.0 REST) in same IIS 7.0 that will run locally on intranet. I would like to know what is the ideal way to deploy these. I am also facing cross domain kind of issues while testing.

Is deploying multiple applications under 'Default Web Site' is called multiple domains or it is called same domain??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you should deploy your client and server in same site with different virtual directories like:

```
http://site/client
http://site/server
```

You should not face with Cross domain issues if you will use the same sitename (binding in IIS) for client and server